# Get the site base url in template.php

Tags: 7, uri, theming

How do i get the base url in template.php?

None of the below works.

```
global $base_url;
global $base_path;
global $base_root;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`base_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7) function which should always work.

To be honest though it just returns `$GLOBALS['base_path']` so your `global $base_path` statement should work fine.

Comment: Yeah but this one worked. May be the $globals are not available in template.php

Comment: This works nicely to build a PHP header for a View that links to the add content page, eg. <a href="<?php echo base_path(); ?>node/add/offer">Create New Offer</a>

Answer (score 9):

`base_path()` only produce `"/"`.

to get the full URL including the domain, you have to use: `$GLOBALS['base_url']`

Comment: It works also in Views PHP to to get the site url <?php print $GLOBALS['base_url'] ."/" ; ?> Written in Global PHP - Output code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only the base URL, you can use the following line.

```
global $base_url;
```

I used it in many projects.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer the question, but seems relevant.
If you're looking for the domain name / base url in order to combine it with the aliased path for a node, instead just get the absolute URL like this:

```
$absoluteurl = url('node/' . $nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));

// http://example.com/content/aliased_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from

```
$GLOBALS['base_root']
```

For more details see http://www.drupal4hu.com/node/310